# Django: custom http header authentification

Tags: python, django, authentication, http-headers

I want to create an authentication for my Django 1.11 project. A user will be authenticated if the request contains the header : `X_USERNAME`.
I am working with generic views so I use `LoginRequiredMixin` to control access.

I made this Custom authentication class:

```
class CustomAuthentication:
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('X_USERNAME')
        logging.warning(username)
        if not username:
            return None
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User(username=username)
            user.is_staff = False
            user.is_superuser = False
            if request.META.get('X_GROUPNAME') == 'administrator':
                user.is_staff = True
                user.is_superuser = True
            user.save()
        return user, None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I added it in my settings :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.file.CustomAuthentication']
```

But I can't make it work. I am redirected to `/accounts/login/?next=` which doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I also tried to create a subclass as described here : [Django RemoteUser documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/auth-remote-user/) since it looks like what I want to achieve:

```
class CustomAuthentication(RemoteUserMiddleware):
    header = 'HTTP_X_USERNAME'
```

It gave me the same result.

Comment: Have you tried placing additional log statements within the `authenticate()` method to see what code path is being executed?

Comment: Yes I did, It seems that this function is never called. Maybe the `authenticate()` method should be called manually within a login page ? Which is not what I want since I don't want to use a login page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  finally managed to find a solution :

In authentication.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import RemoteUserMiddleware

class CustomMiddleware(RemoteUserMiddleware):
    header = 'HTTP_X_USERNAME'
```

The second import is compulsory i am not sure why.

In settings.py:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'app.authentication.CustomMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['app.authentication.RemoteUserBackend']
```

And finally in the class based views I use `LoginRequiredMixin`

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/auth-remote-user/#configuration

Comment: No longer seems to be working:

Attribute Error: ... object has no attribute 'authenticate'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `authenticate()` method must specify `username` and `password` arguments in addition to the `request` argument. Without these, Django ignores the backend (see `django.contrib.auth.__init__._authenticate_with_backend` in Django 2.0).

In your case you should be able to default these arguments to `None` since you're providing the username via a header.

```
class CustomAuthentication:
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        username = request.META.get('X_USERNAME')
        ...
```

Alternatively, use `**credentials`:

```
def authenticate(self, request, **credentials):
```

Comment: I tried it but the `authenticate()` method is still not executed. I think I am not using the right kind of authentication. Still, this is a useful piece of information.

Comment: Strange. When I leave out the `username` and `password` attributes from my test backend the `authenticate()` method does not get called, otherwise Django calls it fine.